# Can you determine the number of workers running in your application

Tags: heroku, sidekiq, heroku-postgres

In order to properly scale our sidekiq workers to the size of our database pool, we came up with a little formula in our configuration

`sidekiq.rb`

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.options[:concurrency] = ((ENV['DB_POOL'] || 5).to_i - 1) / workers
end

def workers
  ... the number of workers configured for our project ...
  (ENV['HEROKU_WORKERS'] || 1).to_i
end
```

We're setting HEROKU_WORKERS by hand, but it would be sweet if there was a way to interrogate the Heroku API from within the application.

Modulo all the things that can happen (workers going up or down, changing the number of workers, etc.), this seems to get us out of the initial problem; where our workers would consume *all* of the database pool connections, and then start crashing on startup.

Comment: I assume that your workers have a line of their in `Procfile`. If that's the case, then the Heroku API can help you. Take a look, for example, at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#dyno or better yet at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#formation

Comment: I am hoping that I don't have to pass an API key to my application. It feels like a security vulnerability.

Comment: You don't need to, and it is indeed unadvisable. The correct pattern is to use a Heroku config var.

Answer (score 1):

The heroku-api gem should provide you this.
https://github.com/heroku/heroku.rb

You should find your API key here: https://dashboard.heroku.com/account

```
require 'heroku-api'
heroku = Heroku::API.new(api_key: API_KEY)
```

Total number of current processes:

```
heroku.get_ps('heroku-app-name').body.count
```

(You should be able to parse this to get total number of workers... or a count of a specific kind of worker, if you have different kinds defined in your Procfile/Heroku app)